# Custom font not uploading in divi theme

Tags: wordpress, divi

[image: custom font no uploading]
I am adding fonts in divi but this showing error, I've tried both file types i.e. ttf and otf but nothing works can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to Divi.

By default WordPress block .ttf file upload.

Here is another topic about that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/396326/82323

You can use [upload_mimes filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_mimes/) to allow ttf upload

To do this, add following code to functions.php

```php
 add_filter('upload_mimes', 'prefix_add_ttf_upload_mimes');
 function prefix_add_ttf_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
      $existing_mimes['ttf'] = 'font/ttf';   
      return $existing_mimes;
 }
```